# PostgreSQL recursive CTE million size tree select by dynamic rank with paging

Tags: postgresql, recursion, tree, recursive-query

My goal is to create a query where I can retrieve a tree by controlling the depth and amount of items returned at each depth sorted by rank descending, which the rank is frequently changing.

I.e.

Give me the tree starting at node id 4, with a maximum depth of 5 (starting at that node) with 5 children max at each level sorted descending by rank.

So I have a tree structure:

```
CREATE TABLE thingtree
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  parent_id uuid,
  text character varying(2048) NOT NULL,
  rank integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT thingtree_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT thingtree_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES thingtree (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to select a node by id and then get all its children, with a configurable limit of records pulled back at each depth and sorted by rank, which is frequently changing.

So I decided to create some data:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
CREATE FUNCTION build_tree (parent_id uuid,max_depth integer,current_depth integer,max_direct_children integer) RETURNS boolean AS $$
   DECLARE
    new_id uuid := uuid_generate_v4();
    BEGIN

    IF current_depth >= max_depth THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

    insert into thingtree VALUES (new_id, parent_id,'test',current_depth + 1);
    FOR i IN 0..(max_direct_children - 1) LOOP
        PERFORM build_tree(new_id,max_depth,current_depth + 1, max_direct_children);
    END LOOP;


    RETURN 0;   
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I then use this function to generate a tree 5 deep with 6 children on each depth

```
select build_tree(NULL ,5, 0 ,6);
```

The above function may take about 20 seconds to run

Next I try to recursively select the data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE thingtrees AS (
    SELECT tt.id,1::INT AS depth, tt.parent_id, tt.text, tt.rank FROM thingtree as tt WHERE id = '207f7c55-1c68-4f0e-9493-416b84b6a0a4'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT st.id, tts.depth + 1 AS depth, st.parent_id, st.text, st.rank
    FROM 
    thingtrees as tts
    JOIN 
    thingtree st 
    on (tts.id = st.parent_id)
    WHERE tts.depth <= 5 order by st.rank

  )
SELECT *
FROM thingtrees
```

Now the depth is fine, it knows not to go past 5, but the issue is I only want a maximum of 5 direct children from each level of node in my tree, but the result returns 6 (because I'm not limiting it).

The issue is if I LIMIT the recursive union from my CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE thingtrees AS (
    SELECT tt.id,1::INT AS depth, tt.parent_id, tt.text, tt.rank FROM thingtree as tt WHERE id = '207f7c55-1c68-4f0e-9493-416b84b6a0a4'
  UNION ALL
    (SELECT st.id, tts.depth + 1 AS depth, st.parent_id, st.text, st.rank
    FROM 
    thingtrees as tts
    JOIN 
    thingtree st 
    on (tts.id = st.parent_id)
    WHERE tts.depth <= 5 order by st.rank limit 5)

  )
SELECT *
FROM thingtrees
```

The issue here is it only returns the first 5 sub nodes of the tree instead of 5 from each depth.

Comment: Copied your example and got 21 rows (5 from each depth). Isn't this what is expected? Are you sure the manually provided `id` is the root node?

Comment: The Sequence is still off, the order by st.rank just orders the entire depth by the rank.